# No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/articles" error on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm very very new to this, and I'm trying to implement a to-do-list which allows use of tags with user authentication. When updating the task, I get a routing error which states No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/articles". I suspect it's because I didn't pass the article ID when updating the article. Could anyone please help guide me on how to solve this? Any advice will be greatly appreciated thank you!

Routes from the error page

```
user_article_path   GET /users/:user_id/articles/:id(.:format)  
articles#show

PATCH   /users/:user_id/articles/:id(.:format)  
articles#update

PUT /users/:user_id/articles/:id(.:format)  
articles#update

DELETE  /users/:user_id/articles/:id(.:format)  
articles#destroy
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users do
      resources :articles 
  end
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#index', as: :tag, :constraints  => { :tag => /[^\/]+/ }

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :content, :name, :tag_list
   before_create :downcase_fields
has_many :taggings , dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings, dependent: :destroy 
 belongs_to :user    
 validates :user_id, presence: true
 validates :title, presence: true,
                   length: { minimum: 1}
  def self.tagged_with(name)
   Tag.find_by_name!(name).articles
  end


   def downcase_fields
      self.title.downcase
   end

def self.tag_counts
  Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
    joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
end

def tag_list
  tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def tag_list=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
    Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end

def self.search(term)
  if term
    where('title LIKE ?', "%#{term}%").order('id DESC')
  else
    order('id DESC') 
  end
end
end
```

articles_controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user

  def index
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @articles = @user.articles.search(params[:term])
#    if params[:tag]
 #     @articles =  @user.articles.tagged_with(params[:tag])
 #   else
 #     @articles =  @user.articles.all
 #   end
  end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @article = @user.articles.find(params[:id])
  end
 def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.new
end

def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to user_articles_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
   @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to user_articles_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @article = @user.articles.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to user_articles_path
end
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :tag_list, :term)
  end


    # Confirms a logged_in user_
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

db.schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_27_093653) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_articles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "tag_id"
    t.bigint "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["article_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_article_id"
    t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "remember_digest"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "articles", "users"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "articles"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags"
  add_foreign_key "taggings", "users"
end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
          redirect_to user_articles_path(@user)

  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the To-Do-Manager!"
      redirect_to user_articles_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

   def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

   def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
```

_form.html.erb(Create and update share the same form)

```
<%= form_with model: @article,url: user_articles_path(@user), local: true do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :Task %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :Deadline %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :tag_list, "Tags (separated by commas)" %><br />
    <%= form.text_field :tag_list %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: I am not using `form_with` only `form_for` but the problem seems to come from your partial `_form.html.erb`. You have a form in this partial. This form should point to the create action of a controller. But yet the path you mention in the form is the path of an index action : `user_articles_path(@user)` This is not correct. In your console type `rails routes` and find the route path to the create action of controller `articles`. Put this route instead. (also don't forget to add `method: post`) .

Comment: Creating new entries work fine though, with that modification I can't create new entries anymore.

Comment: Humm ok. Can you post the full trace for your error. Especially the very line of code that triggers the error ..

Comment: OH sorry I had  syntax error! many thanks! After following your advice, it works! Thanks

Comment: By the way. You mention the same form for creating and editing. To me this is not possible. Because for updating you have to put the path to the update action (+ method `patch`) and add a second value (the value of the user AND the value of the article). For the creation, you have to put the creation path (+ method `post`) and a single value (user id).

Answer (score 1):

Your user article path should be singular according to your routes:

```
<%= form_with model: @article, url: user_article_path(@user), local: true do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You routes requires two parameters: the user (:user_id) and the article (:id), you are only passing the user `user_articles_path(@user)` and also using the plural form, and that route does not exists with that HTTP method.

You have to use `url: user_article_path(@user,@article)` (or you can use the shortcut version `url: [@user, @article]`).